# How to query data from the last 7 days(week) on parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to query data from the last 7 days(week) on parse. How could I do that. I have been researching many articles/forums, but they all seem to be outdated.

Comment: Please give us un example of the data you need to Query and your Query Class Style

Answer (score 0):

You'd use something like:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:604800];
[query whereKey:@"createdAt" lessThan:date];
```

where 604800 is the number of seconds in a week.